# How to search a SQL table for a string?

Tags: mysql, search, phpmyadmin

I want to search one table in phpMyAdmin for a string. For example, if I search "love" and there is a field that has "I love turtles", then it would return the row that it was in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is one thing.  "Full text searches" are another.  Many databases, including mySQL, support both.

SQL has `WHERE myColumn LIKE '%love%'`, if that's what you're looking for.

Even if you implement free text, however, you can still only query on those specific fields you index.

Read here for more details:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html
- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-to-mysql-full-text-search.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Should be straight forward. This could be very fast or slow depending on the size of the table/indices.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE firstColumn LIKE "%love%" OR secondColumn LIKE "%LOVE%" OR thirdColumn LIKE "%LOVE%";
```

Comment: FYI, indexes don't help with that kind of `LIKE` pattern.